# Eslint with TypeScript: No files matching the pattern "'./src/**/*.{js,ts}'" were found

Tags: typescript, eslint

I'm trying to set up Eslint and Prettier with TypeScript (vanilla JS project). Whenever I try to run lint command from the command line, I get this error:

> No files matching the pattern "'./src/**/*.{js,ts}'" were found.

I don't see how could this be wrong, since all my dev files are placed in the "./src" folder. My VSCode is also not giving any feedback on linting.

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-cli serve --mode=development --env [development] --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production --env production",
    "lint": "eslint './src/**/*.{js,ts}' --quiet"
  },
```

My eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    project: ["./tsconfig.json"],
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  extends: [
    "airbnb-typescript/base",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    // Enables eslint-plugin-prettier and eslint-config-prettier. This will display prettier errors as ESLint errors. Make sure this is always the last configuration in the extends array.
    "prettier",
  ],
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
  },
  plugins: ["@typescript-eslint", "import", "prettier"],
  rules: {},
};
```

My tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Make sure to avoid setting module to "CommonJS", or webpack won't be able to tree-shake your code [https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/] */
    "module": "commonjs",
    // Raises errors for declarations with an implied any type "noImplicitAny": true,
    "outDir": "./build/",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    /* Represents the specific ECMAScript version 
    to transpile the code in the browser  */
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "typeRoots": ["src/customTypes", "node_modules/@types"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "downlevelIteration": true
  },
  "include": ["src/"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
}
```

Comment: I have to figure out the reason of a similar problem. It may look funny, but it was all about space in the end of the name of the `src` folder (so it was "src " instead). In VScode you can't see difference if folder tree, so it's tricky